# How to keep change figure size without changing axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure in Matlab with height = 4 inches and width = 11.5 inches (as shown in the first figure). I want to change the height to 2 inches. However, when I set the height = 2 inches, the y axis reduced from 350 to 150. Any one how to fix the y axis when changing the height of the figure? Many thanks!

[image]

[image]

[edit]
Problem solved. I have set yticklabel before I set the figure size. After removing that, there is no problem anymore. Thanks!

Comment: What if you set the 'units' property of the axes to 'normalized'?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to use 'normalized' and 'points' but the problem remains.